# How to change the sitename setting with Pelican?

Tags: github, pelican

I'm a new learner of Pelican.

I have created my personal website including basic settings and some pages by using Pelican, and the following hierarchy has already existed on the local PC:

```
myblog/
├── author
├── content              # Content file (Push on GitHub)
│   └── (pages)
├── output
├── theme
├── develop_server.sh
├── fabfile.py
├── Makefile
├── pelicanconf.py       # Main settings file 
└── publishconf.py
```

Unfortunately, I set the wrong sitename from the beginning when I install Pelican. Right now I'm struggling to change the incorrect sitename from "test" to "XXX's blog". I can rewrite sitename directly in the document called pelicanconf.py. But after that, there's no way to push it on GitHub. So the appearance of my website remains stable.

The only thing I could do is to update the page content again and again, but not the sitename. Because only the content folder is synchronized with my remote GitHub repository.
Is there anyway to change the sitename setting?

Comment: You need to commit and push the changed output. Without more information about how you've structured your configuration, it's hard to suggest how. I have two repos, one for the source (https://github.com/textbook/textbook.github.io-source) and one for the built site, and a Travis job pushing the former to the latter.

Comment: Oh, and I provided a repo to aid setting it up the same way yourself: https://github.com/textbook/pelican_scaffold. The key thing is you need to be pushing the **output**, not the **content**, to the `whatever.github.io` repo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! May I ask is there any way to convert modified pelicanconf.py into output folder file? Ya... I commit and push the modified output folder every time, but this folder doesn't include any sitename setting file. Therefore I can't change it...

Comment: You need to: 1. Change the config `SITENAME`; 2. Run `pelican content` to generate the output; 3. Push the *output* directory into the repo on GitHub. You should also version control everything *but* the output directory in a separate repo.

Comment: The file(in my case it's probably be pelicanconf.py) which contains sitename is parallel with content folder. So even if I follow the first two steps as you mentioned, there's nothing changed with output...lol

Comment: Then I don't know what you've done, because changing the sitename and rebuilding the content works fine for me - the `output` is updated as I'd expect.

Comment: OK. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @jonrsharpe  my bad, the reason why the site name didn't change is because i forgot to refresh the browser. sounds like a dumb mistake but always happens.